# Spotify API: Getting number of times song played, total hours etc

Tags: api, spotify, spotify-app

I  have seen a few questions on stack overflow regarding the spotify api and adding library's  to do things such as

- Count the number of times a song is played (or album/artist)
- Get time data on a user (so like total hours played overall or by song, album or artist etc)

all of the forums where I have seen these questions are going on 5 or 6  years old so im just wondering if anybody has updated information, Ive been having difficulty navigating the api site in regards to finding relevant info on this topic.

if you want a practical idea of what i mean, there was this IOS app called **snd.wave** that pretty much displayed all these statistics for people that used apple music...

Would appreciate any incite!

Answer (score 1):

After getting in contact with devs on the spotify github, there has still been no official addition of this feature to the spotify api as far as i know.

There has been an issue on this since 2015 if you can believe, and still nothing has been added.
Very sad seeing as many other services have had features like this added for ages..

If you wish to try and push them further into an eventual solution feel free to have a go  here

[Spotify Issue Page](https://github.com/spotify/web-api/issues/70)

There have been a few advances but not really to what i desire, for example there is a repository for those who wish to get the count of played songs in an album here....
Havent messed around with it yet though so not too sure as to how useful it is.
[Play count entry](https://github.com/evilarceus/Spotify-PlayCount)

People have expressed problems with this api too, the source i believe was added back in 2019 and may have been cleaned up on the client side, here is a quote from one of the creater himself when he posted a link to it on the ticket page...

*Let's just say: it might be unstable depending on how you use it (I don't even think I put a handler for whenever a Spotify client disconnects from the script lol). It's very possible that you may need to modify the script to fit your needs.*

Pretty much what this king is getting at is that its not properly tested, and sadly he has shut down the public api because as you can imagine it definitely was not worth his while keeping it up with all the requests coming through haha.

So really in short... yes but really no.